# Donate Feature inside iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase, donations

I am planning to develop a free app.  Which could be useful for many people.  So,  I am planning to put a donate button inside my app.  So if any people finds it useful,  they will donate for development.

Is it good if we implement in app purchase to achieve this functionality.

I am not sure is this possible.  Please correct me if this question is wrong and I will remove it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to search. There are multiple questions on how to handle donations.

You have to look for App Store Review Guidelines
https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

See 11.2 - 11.4 and judge if donation to non-charities (Charities covered in 12) are allowed:

I would say no. This is virtual goods not consumed inside the App.

To work around it, let people pay for a different background color or some minor functionality such that you can stay in compliance. Or make 2 versions, telling them to support development by buying the other version (you can link to it). The 2 versions could probably be the same or almost the same.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,  I searched for the answer but I all answer I got was for android.  You idea of two versions is good.  thanks..  I will use it.